# Invalid Cast Exception with C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I'm developing an app in C# and an MS Access 2007 Database.

myTable has 3 columns: Number(Integer), Name(Long Text), Date(Date);

I'm trying to read a value (Integer) from *myTable*, and trying to store it into *TOT* to do other things.
But I continue having an error on
`TOT = reader.GetInt32(x);` saying "Invalid Cast Exception".

Using the Immediate Window, the problem seems to be into `reader.GetInt32(x)`.

Here's the code:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=My_Access_Database; Pwd=1234");
OdbcCommand cmd;
OdbcDataReader reader;
int TOT = 0;

conn.Open();
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select SUM(Number) AS col1 From myTable WHERE Name = '" + label1.Text + "' AND Date=#" + label2.Text + "#;";
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   int x= reader.GetOrdinal("col1");
   if (reader.IsDBNull(x))
   {
     label3.Text = "0.0";
     label4.Text = "0.0";
     label5.Text = "0.0";
   }
   else
   {
      TOT = reader.GetInt32(x);
      //Other things 
   }
}
```

When I execute the query on Access, it works and gives me the value i want.

Comment: My guess would be that `SUM(Number)` is returning a `double` or some other 'non-integer' type.

Comment: What ist Int? TOT is a type of  Int and not int ,are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, it is "int" in my code, wrong typing here.

Is it possible that a SUM of integers returns a non-integer value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `TryParse` method:

```
var result = reader.GetString(x);
int.TryParse(result, out TOT);
```

**UPDATE:**

Try to `CAST` your sum to `int`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select CAST(SUM(Number) as INT) AS col1 From myTable WHERE Name = '" 
    + label1.Text + "' AND Date=#" + label2.Text + "#;";
// the other code is omitted for the brevity
else
{
    TOT = reader.GetInt32(x);
}
```

Comment: Says it cannot cast from System.Double to System.String.
So we got that the SUM(Number) is a Double.
But Number is an Integer column, with Integer values.

Comment: I guess `SUM()` always returns a double type, even when it's only summing integers.

Comment: So what i have to do is TOT = read.GetDouble() and then to convert TOT into an int?

Answer (score 0):

**OK SOLVED:**

Looks like my SUM(Number) returned a Double value, even if the column was an Integer one and filled with integer values.

So you should read the value as a double one and cast it as int.
Here's the code:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=My_Access_Database; Pwd=1234");
OdbcCommand cmd;
OdbcDataReader reader;
int TOT = 0;

conn.Open();
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select SUM(Number) AS col1 From myTable WHERE Name = '" + label1.Text + "' AND Date=#" + label2.Text + "#;";
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   int x= reader.GetOrdinal("col1");
   if (reader.IsDBNull(x))
   {
     label3.Text = "0.0";
     label4.Text = "0.0";
     label5.Text = "0.0";
   }
   else
   {
      TOT = (int)(reader.GetInt32(x));
      //Other things 
   }
}
```